# Does limiting SQLlite fields , result in any performance boast?

Tags: database, sqlite

I have got a table with TEXT and BLOB  fields that i can limit their size (but it is not part of my problem domain ) i want to know :
Does limiting SQLlite fields result in any performance boast or cause less storage consumption ? 
Is Sqllite storing a single field of a single record in a statically allocated memory portion or there is something like a linked list implemented to store TEXT or BLOB data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite does not enforce any limits you set on the columns. For example, you can store practically any length of string in a `VARCHAR(1)` column. Therefore specifying such limits won't affect the performance.

The [internal storage format](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html) is essentially a header containing type and length, followed immediately by the data itself.